# Not Making Vcard Of Facebook contacts

Tags: android

when I simple query my contacts then all contacts shows in list also included facebook contacts and Gmail Contacts but when I use this code then some some vcard are blank ...

```
            String VCard = "";

         Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);
         phones.moveToFirst();
         pDialog.setMax(phones.getCount());
           for(int i =0;i<phones.getCount();i++)
           {

              String lookupKey =  phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
              Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);

              AssetFileDescriptor fd;
             try 
             {
                 fd = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
                 FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
                 byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
                 fis.read(buf);
                 VCard += new String(buf);
                 String y =String.valueOf(i);
                 publishProgress(y);
                 phones.moveToNext();                           
                 Log.d("Vcard",  VCard);
             } 
             catch (Exception e1) 
             {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e1.printStackTrace();
             }

         }

        try {
            FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
              mFileOutputStream.write(VCard.toString().getBytes());
              mFileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI is uri for phones
you should change it to android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI
you will get vcard of contact which is not emty

Comment: and I want, do not copy the code of photo in Vcard then what i do ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333022/donot-insert-image-source-code-when-making-vcard/