# Donot insert image source code when making vcard in api level 8

Tags: android, vcf-vcard

I am making Vcard using this code , now I want In my vcard don't insert code of image , all other things will added in vcard , how I do it .... I'm using this

```
         String VCard = "";

         Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI , null,null, null, null);
         phones.moveToFirst();
         pDialog.setMax(phones.getCount());
           for(int i =0;i<phones.getCount();i++)
           {

              String lookupKey =  phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
              Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);

              AssetFileDescriptor fd;
             try 
             {
                 fd = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
                 FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
                 byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
                 fis.read(buf);
                 VCard += new String(buf);
                 String y =String.valueOf(i);
                 publishProgress(y);
                 phones.moveToNext();                           
                 Log.d("Vcard",  VCard);
             } 
             catch (Exception e1) 
             {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e1.printStackTrace();
             }

         }

        try {
            FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
              mFileOutputStream.write(VCard.toString().getBytes());
              mFileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String lookupKey = phones.getString(phones
    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
Uri vcardUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI
    .buildUpon()
    .appendQueryParameter("nophoto", String.valueOf(true))
    .build();
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(vcardUri, lookupKey);
```

I have modify it again,use in for loop

Comment: it is not working again, it is getting code of image in vcard

Comment: sir enter in this room for chat 
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24164/discussion-between-rohit-and-tushar